# How to read facebook chat messages in Android?

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated the facebook sdk to my app to read facebook updates. The app is reading wall messages without any issue. But I am not getting chat messages. I have given the parameters as parameters.putString("fields", "id,from,message"); . How to get chat messages also? Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

you can get your chat message using facebook SDK..

try this..

```
String s = facebook.request("me/inbox");
System.out.println("Message...."+s);
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: parameters.putString("fields", "id,from,message");                                             String s = facebook.request("me/inbox");